# Operator != vs <>

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators, comparison-operators

Learning python. I’ve doubt on use of following operators:

```
!=  —> Checks if the value of two operands is equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.
<> —> Checks if the value of two operands is equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.
```

The above definition is right([referred from book](http://tutorialspoint.com))? If yes, when we use both operators. Please share your experience with correct situation!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

> The forms `<>` and `!=` are equivalent; for consistency with C, `!=` is preferred; where `!=` is mentioned below `<>` is also accepted. **The `<>` spelling is considered obsolescent.**

(Emphasis mine)

They are equivalent , but you should use `!=` . `<>` operator is not there in Python 3.x as well.

Comment: But but in Python 3 I can do: `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL`.

Comment: :-) , shouldn't it have been `__past__` ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Python standard library Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> Notes:
>
> 1. != can also be written <>, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use !=.

So you should always use the `!=` operator when checking for equality.